# How do I make my webpage stop formatting when I resize the window?

Tags: html, css

I am working on a simple website and whenever I resize the window, my buttons on my top bar keep sliding down below the first line. I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried many solutions such as:

```
body {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

But nothing works. Can someone tell me how to either make my page adjust to peoples window size or make it static so when it adjusts it just cuts off parts of it?
Here is my code:

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <style>
    #button_container {
     width:100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

     body {
     width:100%;
        height:100%;
        position: absolute;
    }


        #title {
        width:100%;
        height: 10%;
    font-family: ecuyerDAX;
        font-size: 55px;
        margin-top:-60px;
        margin-left: 28%;
    color:white;
    }

        button {
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-family: optimus-princeps;
            outline: none;
            border-radius: 3px;
       margin-top:1%;
       color:white;
            background: gray;
       border:1px solid black;
       height:50%;
   margin-left: 1%;
        margin-right: 1%;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(gray, black);
        background: linear-gradient(gray,black);
        }
    #bThree {
     margin-right:55%;

    }
#topBar {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
 height: 12%;
    width:100%;
    background:-webkit-linear-gradient(#20AB53, #0B6F15);  
    background: linear-gradient(#20AB53, #0B6F15);
 } 
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="topBar">
  <div id="button_container">
    <button id="bOne">Home</button>
    <button id="bTwo">About</button>
    <button id="bThree">Contact</button>
     <button id="bFour">Log In</button>
     <button id="bFive">Sign Up</button>
       </div>
  </div>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using fixed values in `px` or `em` instead of percentages for the width properties. They will be non-responsive and will not change width when the screen width changes.

Comment: No problem, glad it worked. Can you please select this answer to show that it addressed the problem?

Answer (score 0):

To stop it from getting too small you would set a min-width of the container. This would make the content get cut off if the space gets smaller.

```
min-width: 1000px;
```

If you want to make it responsive it will be trickier, either through using media queries or flexbox would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

Your buttons are fixed width in px therefore as the width gets less the buttons take more and more space up until they eventually do not fit and need to wrap.

If your buttons were a percentage width they would not wrap, though it would not be a good solution.

I think doing a float:right for the right hand two would stop them wrapping so early (and float:left for the left hand three). Though they would still wrap once the left hand and right hand ones meet each other.

Answer (score 0):

Give a #bThree margin-right isn't good idea. You can replace it with `#bFour, #bFive { float: right; }`

It is possible to specify all the margin properties in one property: `margin: top right bottom left`. As your example you can change it to: `margin: 1% 1% 0 1%` or `margin: 1% 1% 0`. Googling "Shorthand property" for more explanation.

```css
body {
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 0;
}
#topBar {
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#20AB53, #0B6F15);  
  background: linear-gradient(#20AB53, #0B6F15);
}
button {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-family: optimus-princeps;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin: 1%;
  color:white;
  background: gray;
  border:1px solid black;
  line-height: 25px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(gray, black);
  background: linear-gradient(gray,black);
}
#bFour, #bFive {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="topBar">
  <div id="button_container">
    <button id="bOne">Home</button>
    <button id="bTwo">About</button>
    <button id="bThree">Contact</button>
    <button id="bFour">Log In</button>
    <button id="bFive">Sign Up</button>
  </div>
</div>
```